# How can I make all my skeleton elements responsive in terms of width?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, react-native, material-ui

I'm working on making Skeletons from MUI within my code responsive. While the container is responsive, the Skeletons are not adapting properly. Can someone help me troubleshoot and improve my code for responsiveness?

Thank you in advance!

```
<div
  style={{
    height: "2165px",
    maxWidth: "1082px",
    background: "white",
    padding: "24px",
    borderRadius: "15px",
    marginBottom: "46px",
  }}
>
  <div class="A" style={{ display: "inline-flex" }}>
    <Skeleton
      variant="Text"
      width={320}
      height={48}
      style={{ borderRadius: "10px" }}
    />
    <Skeleton
      variant="Text"
      width={320}
      height={48}
      style={{ borderRadius: "10px", marginRight: "35px" }}
    />
    <Skeleton
      variant="Text"
      width={320}
      height={48}
      style={{ borderRadius: "10px", marginRight: "35px" }}
    />
  </div>
  <br />
  <br />
  <Skeleton
    variant="Text"
    width={100}
    height={25}
    style={{ borderRadius: "5px" }}
  />
  <div style={{ paddingTop: "20px" }}>
    <div style={{ marginRight: "10px", display: "inline-flex" }}>
      <Skeleton
        variant="circular"
        width={20}
        height={20}
        style={{ borderRadius: "10px" }}
      />
      <Skeleton
        variant="Text"
        width={100}
        height={20}
        style={{ borderRadius: "5px", marginRight: "8px" }}
      />

      <Skeleton
        variant="circular"
        width={20}
        height={20}
        style={{ borderRadius: "10px", marginRight: "20px" }}
      />
      <Skeleton
        variant="Text"
        width={100}
        height={20}
        style={{ borderRadius: "5px", marginRight: "8px" }}
      />

      <Skeleton
        variant="circular"
        width={20}
        height={20}
        style={{ borderRadius: "10px", marginRight: "20px" }}
      />
      <Skeleton
        variant="Text"
        width={100}
        height={20}
        style={{ borderRadius: "5px", marginRight: "8px" }}
      />

      <Skeleton
        variant="circular"
        width={20}
        height={20}
        style={{ borderRadius: "10px", marginRight: "20px" }}
      />
      <Skeleton
        variant="Text"
        width={100}
        height={20}
        style={{ borderRadius: "5px", marginRight: "8px" }}
      />

      <Skeleton
        variant="circular"
        width={20}
        height={20}
        style={{ borderRadius: "10px", marginRight: "20px" }}
      />
      <Skeleton
        variant="Text"
        width={100}
        height={20}
        style={{ borderRadius: "5px", marginRight: "8px" }}
      />
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <Skeleton
      variant="Text"
      width={240}
      height={48}
      style={{ borderRadius: "10px" }}
    />
    <br />
    <br />
    <Skeleton
      variant="Text"
      width={110}
      height={27}
      style={{ borderRadius: "10px" }}
    />
    <br />
    <Skeleton
      variant="Text"
      width={1035}
      height={300}
      style={{ marginTop: "20px", borderRadius: "12px" }}
    />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <Skeleton
      variant="Text"
      width={460}
      height={48}
      style={{ borderRadius: "10px" }}
    />
    <br />
    <br />
    <Skeleton
      variant="Text"
      width={80}
      height={30}
      style={{ borderRadius: "10px" }}
    />
    <br />
    <Skeleton
      variant="Text"
      width={180}
      height={50}
      style={{ borderRadius: "10px", marginRight: "6px" }}
    />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <Skeleton
      variant="Text"
      width={130}
      height={30}
      style={{ borderRadius: "10px", marginRight: "6px" }}
    />
    <br />
    <br />
    <div style={{ display: "flex" }}>
      <Skeleton
        variant="circular"
        width={157}
        height={157}
        style={{ borderRadius: "157px" }}
      />
      <Skeleton
        variant="Text"
        width={300}
        height={30}
        style={{ borderRadius: "10px", marginRight: "25px", marginTop: "20px" }}
      />
      <br />
      <Skeleton
        variant="Text"
        width={410}
        height={54}
        style={{
          borderRadius: "10px",
          marginRight: "-300px",
          marginTop: "80px",
        }}
      />
      <Skeleton
        variant="Text"
        width={100}
        height={50}
        style={{ borderRadius: "10px", marginRight: "8px", marginTop: "80px" }}
      />
    </div>
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <Skeleton
      variant="Text"
      width={1035}
      height={300}
      style={{ borderRadius: "12px" }}
    />
    <Skeleton
      variant="Text"
      width={"100%"}
      height={300}
      style={{ marginTop: "30px", borderRadius: "12px" }}
    />
  </div>
</div>;
```

Comment: What do you mean with adapting properly? Since you set the width and height, it is fixed.What would you want it to respond to?

Comment: @Domino987 i want to make ir all responsive, can u modify the whole codes plz.?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the purpose of this website. We can give you solutions, but not just modify the code. You need to use percentage values instead of hard coded values. You could also try to use the mui grid with fixed widths and overflows.

Comment: I have met the same issue today. My solution is to use React npm package "React Skeleton" + set for skeleton component: style{{width: 100%, height: 100%}}. Despite fixed sizes inside - it's responsive outside. Aspect ratio is determined by viewbox.